# Antd <Option> changes render behavior by the pure existence of non executed(!) code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design for the first time in a project. Using the `<Option>` and `<Select>` component I have run into the strangest bug I've ever had. The pure existence if code, which is NOT EXECUTED changes the render behavior of the `<Option>`.

The difference is, that the first time (with the code) it displays a number (3) in the `<Option>` and the second time (without the code) it displays a string ("Schraube").

I don't know how much code I am allowed to share, but I recorded a short video which shows the bug.

(The code which prints "GETS CALLED" only runs after I change the select option, during the render process it doesn't get executed.)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY2NPgP5x6A

I'd like to hear your thoughts on it.

Comment: Some may not be able to watch the video, I would share code.

Comment: Also describe the difference in render behavior.

Comment: It only displays the "3" after "GETS CALLED" has been logged, so the code in question is being executed.

Comment: FWIW, the question itself isn't bad at all, just the presentation. I strongly recommend copying the relevant portions of code here so they can provide proper context to any future readers that might have a similar issue. The code that's highlighted in the video is clear enough to explain the problem. If you're concerned about propriety, then you should try to replicate the behavior with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do this, and I'm sure the question will be received better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you have:

```
if (a) {
    console.log("GETS CALLED");
    return false;
}

return true;
```

When this code gets executed, your option isn't formatted to a user-friendly display.

In the second you have just:

```
return true;
```

In which case it is being formatted correctly.

Note this is not just removing the `console.log` statement, and you're not just enabling some trivial `if` statement. **You're changing the the return value of the function.** Since this is in a call to `.filter` you're changing what values get passed to `.map` which actually formats the option for display purposes.

If you were to try:

```
if (a) {
    console.log("GETS CALLED");
}

return true;
```

You'd see that the value gets formatted, *and* your `console.log` statement gets hit.

**Update** What I think you're trying to accomplish is to have the second dropdown exclude the option that was selected in the first dropdown. In that case you'll need to render different option arrays for each item. Also be sure to include the item that is selected for the current dropdown, so that the display is correct on the selected item. Something along these lines should help:

```
const orderForm = this.state.order.map((o, i) => {
   const options = this.state.parts
       .filter(p => {
           // look for any *other* order that has this part id selected
           const a = this.state.order.find((o2) => o2 !== o && o2.partId === p.id);
           return !a;
       })
       .map((p) => (<Option ... />));

   return (
      <Select>
         {options}
      </Select>
   );
});
```

Or if you want to render the `<Option>`'s only once, you could do something like this:

```
const allOptions = this.state.parts.map((p) => [p.id, (<Option ... />)]);

const orderForm = this.state.order.map((o, i) => {
   const options = allOptions 
       .filter(([partId]) => {
           // look for any *other* order that has this part id selected
           const a = this.state.order.find((o2) => o2 !== o && o2.partId === partId);
           return !a;
       })
       .map(([_, opt]) => opt);

   return (
      <Select>
         {options}
      </Select>
   );
});
```

Comment: The console log is only to make things clearer. Of course I know that the return value is changed. But the values of the filter don't changes, because when the page gets loaded the find() method always returns undefined. So the return false statement never gets executed. There fore i put the console log there. I made another video to show you that the values don't change. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSojDJkGW5Y

Comment: Watch the video carefully. "GETS CALLED" gets never printed on the page load, only if i change the option of the select.

Comment: @Ruudy but the rendering difference ALSO only happens after you change the option of the select. There is no rendering difference on page load.

Comment: Of course. Watch the second video, compare the values which get returned by the filter and then look what is inside the <Option>. Inside the option is p.name, which if equal both times (you can see it in the console). I know this looks like a shitpost, but watch it carefully and look what stands in the Option.

Comment: In fact even if i write <Option key={ p.id } value={ p.id }>SOME TEXT</Option> it renders the number, if the if (a) code is present.

Comment: @Ruudy What's happening is that when you return false from within the filter, the `part` doesn't get transformed into an `<Option>`, and therefore what get's rendered into the `<Select>`'s text field is just the selected value, in this case `3`.

Comment: But when i return false "manually" it works. I know how shitty this post looks.

Comment: @Ruudy See my updated answer. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Ruudy I think you're still not quite understanding the problem. Because you filter out the selected item (`return false`) it doesn't generate an `<Option>` for that item. If you want to display `Zahnrad` when `23455` is selected, there *must* be an `<Option value="23455">Zahnrad</Option>` in the set of available options.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time. The post my look like a complete shitpost, but the solution isn't that obvious. Thank you for taking the time and solving the problem, despite you had only a small code insight. Not like others wich just downvote. (Of course it was stupid, anyways..)